# Jupyter server process failed to start Resolved value for exe path is null

Tags: jupyter-notebook, dataspell

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEodV.png)

I've just downloaded DataSpell for Jupyter Notebook. Try to run a cell this error keep pop up. Does anyone know what this mean and how to fix it? Thank you!

Meaning of the error and how to fix it.